# MongoDB too many open connections when auto reconnect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm creating api server using nodejs+mongodb (mongodb-native). My app are open connection only one time and reuse it.

When my app connected to database (mongod log)

```
2015-07-28T02:28:06.485+0700 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:62621 (0 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:28:06.486+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62622 #4 (1 connection now open)
2015-07-28T02:28:06.488+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62623 #5 (2 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:28:06.488+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62624 #6 (3 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:28:06.491+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62625 #7 (4 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:28:06.491+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62626 #8 (5 connections now open)
```

"5 connections now open" Ok It's correctly.

Then I'm try to shutdown mongod for 10 seconds then start mongod again.

```
2015-07-28T02:30:39.533+0700 I NETWORK  [conn22] end connection 127.0.0.1:63002 (21 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:30:39.534+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63003 #23 (22 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:30:39.538+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63004 #24 (23 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:30:39.538+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63005 #25 (24 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:30:39.538+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63006 #26 (25 connections now open)
2015-07-28T02:30:39.539+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63007 #27 (26 connections now open)
```

"26 connections now open" Something wrong?

here is my connection options

```
options: {
        server: {
            poolSize: 5,
            auto_reconnect: true,
            reconnectTries: -1,
            reconnectInterval: 1000,
        }
    }
```

This is problem or not? How to fix it?